# Risk assessment for ablation of Earth-collision course object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have seen articles dismissing fragmentation of an incoming Earth-colliding object as too risky because of resulting collisions of smaller resulting pieces. What would be the adverse effect of vaporizing or reducing the surface to tiny particles in order to significantly reduce the mass of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Ablation of the surface inherently is less risky than fragmentation of the entire object, as the trajectories of fragments are not predictable with any great degree of accuracy in the absence of knowing the exact composition, internal stresses, and fault lines of the object.

However, a possibly greater danger than the unforeseen trajectories of fragments would be if some actor intentionally ablated the surface of a near-space object in order to direct it toward a rival nation, or otherwise toward a specific spot on the Earth's surface.

Several impact-avoidance techniques, such as ablation (http://www.strath.ac.uk/ascl/research/missionsystems/asteroiddeflectiontechnologies/laserablationexperiments/,
gravity tractors (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_tractor), 
ion beam shepherds (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_Beam_Shepherd), 
mass drivers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_driver), 
focused nuclear explosions creating impulse jets on the surface of the object, or even rocket engines affixed to the surface of a near space object, might be capable of directing the object so as to target a rival actor on the Earth's surface.

So, the chief danger of ablation would be if the technique were accurate enough not only to deflect an object away from the Earth's orbit, but to convert otherwise harmless objects into missiles capable of targeting specific points on the Earth's surface.

It doesn't seem to me that ablation has sufficiently precise steering control and fine tuning capability to change the trajectory of an asteroid originally destined for a close encounter into a targeting missile.  Perhaps because of this, it might be wise to put the planet's effort into ablation rather than into more easily steerable methods.

In addition, ablation may be useful for mining the surface of asteroids.

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the mass of the object by fragmenting it, you just create many more smaller pieces. Unless you do this at a sufficiently large distance (so that you create a lot of additional angular momentum and the particles will miss the Earth), what you are doing instead is turning a rifle into a shot gun.

While a rifle bullet is quite deadly if it hits you, it doesn't take a lot to miss. With a shotgun, you spread the projectiles over a larger area - increasing the chance of hitting the target, but reducing the amount of deadly power.

When a meteorite comes towards earth you would have to be very sure that the fragmentation doesn't turn a near miss into a certain hit.